# Is it ethical / legal to publish results obtained by AI if it was trained with only own results?

Tags: authorship, publishability, generative-ai

I understand that using AI results and publish them as your own violates academic ethics, if it is legal at all. I also understand that AI in its current state is probably far from finding new insights that can be published.

However, if researchers train an AI, e.g. ChatGPT, using exclusively their own published papers and draft research results, is it ethical / legal to publish the new discoveries of the AI under their name? Is it necessary to indicate that some results were obtained by aim of AI?

This question can be viewed with another perspective. It is common practice in some academic circles that the scientific advisers publish their PhD students' results as their own, even without mentioning it. They even can justify this action by saying that they guided the student and the new result was a logical continuation of this guidance. In my question, AI plays the role of the PhD student.

Comment: I removed the additional questions, as with them your question might be closed due to asking too many things at the same time.

Comment: Can I add these related questions in a comment?

Comment: No. According to the site rules, please ask only one question at a time. You can ask a new question, but do not sidestep the rule by asking more things in the comments. Otherwise your comment might be deleted.

Comment: "It is common practice in some academic circles that the scientific advisers publish their PhD students' results as their own" If you really want to go with the analogy. do these advisors disclose that the results are obtained from the work of their students?
If not: common practice does not mean it is an acceptable practice (although the dissonance between the norm, the rule and what is acceptable will make life a pain for everyone involved)

Comment: *It is common practice in some academic circles that the scientific advisers publish their PhD students' results as their own, even without mentioning it.* --- Although you did qualify with "some", it's worth noting that in math almost the opposite is often the case. For example, see the extensive discussion answers/comments to the mathoverflow question [When should a supervisor be a co-author?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/57337/15780) (e.g. [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/57339/15780) and comments to [this other answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/57391/15780)).

Comment: Well, probably to clarify myself, what role should be regarded to AI: as a tool to obtain the result (aka: footnote "In my research I uses XYZ software to compute the result") or as a owner of intellectual property (aka: "Some helpful results were obtained by XYZ")?

Comment: Aside:  I saw recently a ruling that output of an AI cannot be copyrighted.

Answer (score 3):

Machine learning models *already* generate plenty of research. Computational chemistry (my area) is seeing a boom in models that can take a small set of expensive but accurate calculations and extrapolate them into equally accurate calculations of configurations that the models have not seen before. Such "ML calculators" can slash the time taken for calculations by orders of magnitude. Others can (almost literally) [dream up designer proteins that bind to your target of choice](https://www.bakerlab.org/2023/07/11/diffusion-model-for-protein-design/). [Entire laboratories](https://www.matter.toronto.edu/basic-content-page/ai-for-discovery-and-self-driving-labs) are being run with an AI hand at the wheel.

But when you say

> e.g. ChatGPT

I take it you are not referring to such "technical" models, which use ML to speed up the technical tasks of running simulations and validating protein folds and such. I guess you are thinking of something more futuristic, like Tony Stark asking JARVIS "Hey, what would a room temperature superconductor look like?" and JARVIS replying, after a morning of prompt-crunching, "well, first sinter lead(II) oxide with lead(II) sulfate to form a lanarkite ..."

The problem is that anything like a Generative *Pre-trained* Transformer represents a fraught usage of licensed data even before your hypothetical scientist has logged in. To learn language, HypothetiCarl (or whatever the bot is called) will almost certainly have been trained on something like [Books3](https://huggingface.co/datasets/the_pile_books3), containing in its 100GB of data about [60,000 non-fiction and 120,000 fiction titles](https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2023/08/books3-ai-meta-llama-pirated-books/675063/), all pirated. So, from *that* perspective, using a general generative large language model for anything at all where IP is in question is at least fraught if not downright wrong.

It also underestimates how science is inherently social and founded upon *people helping other people* discover great things. AI-science will need to be repeatable and reputable to help other scientists. (What if "A Remarkably Energetic Synthesis Of A Room-Temperature Superconductor, by Tony Stark and JARVIS" actually prescribes a recipe that, when attempted in competitors' labs, will blow them sky high?) The kind of secrecy that would lead a scientist to hide an AI's contributions (or, for that matter, *their PhD students' contributions*) would also make them extremely difficult to collaborate with and would prevent them from progressing in science.

Wherever science is progressing well, it is progressing in the direction of becoming more open, more transparent, more replicable, and more democratically approachable. A hypothetical scientist who used AI without stating so would run counter to every instinct in that bundle and would not make it far.

Comment: Shern Ren Tee, your point about impossibility to train AI exclusively upon own research is valid. Still, there is different ways to regard someone's contribution. If you use Taylor series, his contribution is regarded in the method name. Some more specific results are regarded in bibliography. If some researcher / adviser made a substantial suggestion, but remains outside of research, he can be regarded in a footnote. If someone worked together with author, he is probably put as a co-author.